What's the best way to update ~500 entities with EF Core?
Right now I loop through each entity and call ExecuteUpdateAsync then after the loop I call CommitAsync, but I'd like to know if there is a better way for updating ~500 records?
I see this bulk extensions library, but never used it and don't know if it would help?
Additionally, this code is running in a Azure Function in the Cloud, so it isn't really that time dependent. I don't care if it takes 10 seconds or 1 min to run, just as long as it doesn't bog down the DB for other users using a website that shares the DB.
I'm using EF Core with a Code First approach, so I'd like to stay within the scope of EF Core.
Lastly, my data isn't coming from my DB, it's coming from a web service that's being called to fetch the data.
// About 500 transfers, data doesn't come from DB
var transfers = new List<(string, decimal?, long, string, string)>();

using var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();

try
{
    foreach (var transfer in transfers)
    {
        var stripeTransfersResult = await _dbContext.StripeTransfers
          .Where(p => p.TransferId == transfer.Item1)
          .ExecuteUpdateAsync(setters => setters
            .SetProperty(p => p.ExchangeRate, transfer.Item2)
            .SetProperty(p => p.ExchangeAmount, transfer.Item3)
            .SetProperty(p => p.ExchangeCurrency, transfer.Item4)
            .SetProperty(p => p.StripePayoutId, transfer.Item5)
          );
    }

    await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);
}
catch (DbException ex)
{
    // handle exception
}


AFAIK, Using ExecuteUpdateAsync & SetProperty is the most efficient way to do updates with EF Core. Not sure if the transaction makes a difference.

Have you tried fetching 500 records into memory updating them and calling SaveChanges (alternatively you can attach them to save the roundtrip but it can have some edge cases to think about)?

@PeterB If I'm not hallucinating for example for SQL Server EF Core can do some dirty staff with batching several exec 'update ...' into one roundtrip which can save some time here. But this if course requires checking). It's been some time since I have checked the behavior here.

FYI - I guess you could say I do fetch the data into memory, because the initial fetch into StripeTransfers comes from a web service, so I do in fact read the data into memory. It's not being fetched from my DB. Also, time isn't really that crucial because this update is occurring in an Azure function in the cloud, so it's not really time dependent, meaning, it's not a controller running from my web app waiting to return a response to a user on a web website. This is being done on the back end in the cloud.

Which DBMS are you using? Add tag.

In Sql Server you can use Table Valued Parameter. It will be much more efficient than your current code. There are several answers how to use TVP in EF Core.

Sql Server in Azure

@HansKeﬆing that's what I'm asking! Is there a more efficient way of running through and updating each row.

ExecuteUpdate is not best fit for your need.
ExecuteUpdate is useful when having a big data set where for example column(s) need to be set to same value or incremented with some number.
When need to update each row with specific values regular approach would be to load all those into memory, make the changes, and then call SaveChanges.
Example:
transfers = transfers.OrderBy(a => a.Item1);
itemIds = transfers.Select(a => a.Item1).ToList();
var entities = await _dbContext.StripeTransfers.Where(a => itemIds.Contains(a.TransferId)).OrderBy(a => a.TransferId).ToListAsync();//SQL IN
foreach (int i = 0; i < entities.Count(); i++)
{
  entity = entities[i];
  transfer = transfers[i];
  entity.ExchangeRate = transfer.Item2;
  entity.ExchangeAmount = transfer.Item3;
  entity.ExchangeCurrency = transfer.Item4;
  entity.StripePayoutId = transfer.Item5;
}
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

One more way could be using Attach like:
var m = new myModel { PrimaryKey = 1, OtherProperty = 5 };
ctx.Attach(m);
ctx.entry(m).Property(nameof(m.OtherProperty)).IsModified = true;
ctx.SaveChanges();

But those can be sometimes slow for lot of data and to speed the operation up you could use BulkExtensions library the following way:
var entities = new List<StripeTransfer>();
foreach (var transfer in transfers)
{
  var entity = new StripeTransfer();
  entity.TransferId= transfer.Item1;
  entity.ExchangeRate = transfer.Item2;
  entity.ExchangeAmount = transfer.Item3;
  entity.ExchangeCurrency = transfer.Item4;
  entity.StripePayoutId = transfer.Item5;
  entities.Add(entity);
}
var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig { 
  UpdateByProperties = new List<string> { nameof(Item.TransferId) }, 
  PropertiesToInclude= new List<string> { nameof(Item.ExchangeRate), nameof(Item.ExchangeAmount), nameof(Item.ExchangeCurrency), nameof(Item.StripePayoutId) },
};
await _dbContext.BulkUpdateAsync(entities, bulkConfig);

PS I'm the author of the lib.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't fetching all the transfers from the DB that need to be updated be extremely inefficient if those entities are large (large amount of properties)? If I fetch those entities, I'm fetching the whole entity, not just the properties I want to update! So wouldn't ExecuteUpdate be more appropriate, in terms of memory used? In many cases I won't have ~500 rows to update, more like 5-500 but maybe sometimes I'll have a few more. It's hard to say because I have't gone live yet.

I just installed BulkExtensions and referenced BulkConfig and BulkUpdate in my project, but I'm getting an error referencing Item.TransferId what is Item? If these are lists of strings, shouldn't it be "TransferId"?

It dependes on numbers of rows vs number of columns.
Also I have added one more way using Attach.
As for the BULK it sohold be 'entiteis' instead of 'items', code is updated.

StripeTransfer has 26 columns and I imagine there will be somewhere between 10-500 rows per update. Is your library "BulkExtensions" more efficient in performing this type of bulk update than your first 2 solutions?

BulkExtensions is very efficient when having several thousand or even milion+ rows, something that regular EF can't even handle.
Not sure what the difference would be for few hunder row, you could try all ways and make a test for comparison.

What do you mean EF can't handle it? If I had, say 1000 rows to update, what would happen? Would an exception get thrown?

1000 will work, 10 000 will have wait sometime, 100 000 very slow and could timeout, 1 mil or more would throw exception. That is the purpose of the library, to speed up large amount of data.

ok thanks for the info. It sounds like I might not need your library. I predict, because I'm not live yet, that I'll be updating ~5-500 rows per run. Think of an Uber driver, he won't have more than a few hundred rides per payout period (2 weeks). He might have a little more, maybe 1,000, but unlikely. My biggest concern is how many times I call this function. If I have 1,000,000 drivers and they all get paid on the same day, I'd be running all these updates at once and updating the DB with a high frequency. I'm concerned that might slow the DB down for the users on the website.

As far as I can tell, you should, in fact, use the ExecuteUpdateAsync and SetProperty pattern for batch updating, but I believe that this is actually meant for batch updates where we set the same value for all of the items included in the batch.
The ExecuteUpdateAsync & SetProperty method generates the following SQL Query:
UPDATE [StripeTransfers] SET (ExchangeRate, ExchangeAmount...) = (Value1, Value2...);

In your case, this won't really work exactly as intended. As far as I can tell, by wrapping your foreach method inside a transaction, you should be able to take advantage of the fact that you'll save yourself the overhead of the first round-trip to the database, storing the object in memory, and updating the ef change tracker, but you'll still be executing an update statement for each of your objects. Still, this seems like the most optimized solution.
You'll also find more information regarding EF's batching behavior in Microsoft's documentation here.

I don't think SaveChangesAsync is necessary with ExceuteUpdateAsync

My bad, you're right! Updated the answer to reflect this!
